# Restricting method execution from other class method

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

Somebody asked me this question and I am not able to find out the solution, I have a class `A` with method `a1` and `a2`:

`Class A {a1() a2()}`:

and a class `B` with method `b1` and `b2`:

`Class B {b1() b2()}`

Considering multithreading environment i want to stop execution of b1 when a1 is called and same applies for b2 and a2. Both the objects are independent. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class A {
    private final Object lock;

    public A(Object lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void a1() { 
        synchronized(lock) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

public class B {
    private final Object lock;

    public B(Object lock) {
        this.lock = lock;
    }

    public void b1() { 
        synchronized(lock) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now if you construct an A and a B and pass them the same lock object, The `a1()` and `b1()` methods of those two objects will be mutually exclusive:

```
Object lock = new Object();
A a = new A(lock);
B b = new B(lock);
```

If you want `a2()` and `b2()` to be mutually exclusive, then pass another lock object, and make these two methods synchronized on this other lock object.

Comment: would in not be better to also make `Object lock = new Object();` final

Comment: The caller doesn't care. Once A and B are constructed, they have a reference to the lock, and what matters is that their reference isn't reassigned to another lock object.

Answer (score 0):

I had given a try on it in my [blog](http://bhat86.blogspot.in/2011/06/mutual-exclusion-among-2-different.html). I hope it helps

The idea here is to create class `C` and `D` as follows

```
class C {

    static A a = new A(); //I have created new instances of A and B
    static B b = new B(); //The same instances can be passed to C and D via constructor

    static synchronized void da1() {
        a.a1();
    }

    static synchronized void db1() {
        b.b1();
    }
}

class D {

    static A a = new A();
    static B b = new B();

    static synchronized void ca2() {
        a.a2();
    }

    static synchronized void cb2() {
        b.b2();
    }
}
```

If you consider the case where `A`'s `a1()` and `B`'s `b1()` should be mutually exclusive, then you should redirect both of them through `C`.

In `C`, both the methods are `static synchronized`, that means only one method can be executed at any instance of time (lock is the `class` object itself). Hence when `a1()` is executed, thread executing `b1()` will wait and vise versa.